# Wrong answer in Abbreviations problem using DP

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Can someone explain what is wrong with my code? I am getting "Abort called" in 7 test cases. Rest are successful.

I have a 2d dp array with of size: n+1 x m+1 were n and m are sizes of a and b respectively. So, the row represent string a and columns represent string b.

First, I set dp[0][0] to 1 since it is possible to turn empty string into empty.

So, initially, i am checking if I can turn any substring of a into the empty string (in the first single for-loop). This is true for all substrings of a without any capital letters. As soon as there is a capital letter, the rest of the substrings cannot be converted.

Then (in the next double for-loop), I am examining all the cases.

**Case 1**: a[i-1] == b[i-1] -> if both the letter are the exact same, then dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j-1]

**Case 2**: a[i-1] is lower case (this has 2 sub cases):

**Case 2.1**: a[i-1] and b[j-1] are the same letter (but not the same case) -> then we can either change a[i-1] or delete it . So:
dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j-1] || dp[i-1][j].
**Case 2.2**: a[i-1] and b[j-1] are not the same -> in this case, we can only delete a[i-1] since it is lower case . So: dp[i][j] =
dp[i-1][j]

Link to problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/abbr/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=dynamic-programming

P.S. The main logic of the program is just inside the abbreviation() function.

Code (EDITTED):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

bool isSame(const char &a, const char &b)
{
    return a == b || abs(a - b) == 32;
}

bool isLower(const char &a)
{
    return a > 90 && a < 123;
}
// Complete the abbreviation function below.
string abbreviation(const string &a, const string &b)
{

    int n = a.size(), m = b.size();
    if (m > n)
        return "NO";
    vector<vector<bool>> dp(n + 1, vector<bool>(m + 1, 0));
    dp[0][0] = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        if (isLower(a[i - 1]) && dp[i - 1][0])
            dp[i][0] = 1;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
        {
            if (a[i - 1] == b[j - 1])
                dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j - 1];
            if (isLower(a[i - 1]))
            {
                if (isSame(a[i - 1], b[j - 1]))
                    dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j - 1] || dp[i - 1][j];
                else if (dp[i - 1][j])
                {
                    dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return dp[n][m] ? "YES" : "NO";
}

int main()
{

    int t;
    cin >> t;

    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    while (t--)
    {
        string a, b;
        getline(cin, a);
        getline(cin, b);
        cout << abbreviation(a, b) << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please show a [mre] with inputs, expected outputs and actual outputs

Comment: thise code was not written to be read by someone else. `ll` , `vi`, `vvi`... ?!? why are you doing this?

Comment: ironically your code would be shorter without those code shortening tricks

Comment: @idclev463035818 Sorry. That is just some shortcuts I use in CP so i can write faster. I have edited my code and removed all the redundancies. Please take a look again

Comment: @AlanBirtles Please see if the code is ok now. As for the inputs and outputs, they are all correct for the ones that are unlocked in hackerrank. The issue is with the ones that are locked so I doubt pasting the one that are ok will be helpful. In case you still need those, please let me know

Comment: what input causes wrong output? In case you don't know you have to find out.

Comment: @idclev 463035818 those inputs are locked which is why I can't view those. I have provided the link to the problem. Please paste the code there and see.

Comment: you should always write your own tests. Not writing tests is not an option. Not finding a test case that fails is unfortunate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in the code is **"Segmentation fault"**.

Because of the following loop:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
```

As the loop is iterating till i(which could be greater than m i.e. the size of b). That's the reason for the **Segmentation fault**.

Now the following code passes all the test cases.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

bool isSame(const char&a, const char&b){
    return a==b || abs(a-b)==32;
}

bool isLower(const char&a){
    return a >90 && a<123;
}

// Complete the abbreviation function below.
string abbreviation(string a, string b) {
    
    int n = a.size(), m = b.size();
    
    if(m>n)
        return "NO";
    
    int dp[n+1][m+1] = {};
    dp[0][0] = 1;
    
    for(int i=1; i<=n; ++i)
        if(isLower(a[i-1]) && dp[i-1][0]) 
            dp[i][0] = 1;
    
    for(int i=1; i<=n; ++i)
        for(int j =1; j<=min(i,m); ++j){
            if(a[i-1]==b[j-1]) 
                dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j-1];
            if(isLower(a[i-1]))
            {
                if(isSame(a[i-1], b[j-1])) 
                    dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j-1] || dp[i-1][j];
                else if(dp[i-1][j]) 
                    dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j];
            }
            
        }

    return dp[n][m] ? "YES" : "NO";
}

int main()
{

    int q;
    cin >> q;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    for (int q_itr = 0; q_itr < q; q_itr++) {
        string a;
        getline(cin, a);

        string b;
        getline(cin, b);

        string result = abbreviation(a, b);

         cout << result << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ohh. I see. that makes sense. I was wondering what was wrong with my logic for so long...lol

Comment: @Ak01 If my answer has solved your problem, Could you accept/upvote that, please?

Comment: Sure, no problem.